# Is the definition of recursion and iteration in signal processing different from computer science?

Tags: theory

I was talking to my advisor today about this. He is a very experienced professor in this field, so I assume he is very knowledgable about it.

He pointed out that in signal processing, the word **iteration** means the repeated process that you repeat to gain a more accurate result (not the exact word, but generally this meaning). On the other hand, the word **recursion** means the actions that go on with every time instant. Basically, iterations happen within the same time instant, and recursions happen along the time instants.

However, as far as I can remember from the algorithm course that I took in undergrad, recursion means a function that can call itself repeatedly until there's no data left. The [wikipedia page of recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion) is consistent with my understanding.

What I guess is the situation now is, probably the definitions of recursion and iteration are different in SP than CS. I wanted to know, how exactly they are defined in signal processing. It is also possible that there is a different layer of the meaning of recursion that I didn't know, which made the two ways of understanding consistent. If there was a textbook or material that has the formal definition of them, it would be great.

I wanted to bring up the wikipedia page today during the meeting, but we ran out of time. I tried to google but couldn't find the answer. Guess I will ask him about it next time when we meet. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, the term *iteration* in DSP is usually used in the [mathematical sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration#Mathematics), i.e., for describing [iterative methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_method) solving certain numerical problems. The [power method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_iteration) for computing the largest eigenvalue of a matrix and its corresponding eigenvector is a typical example of such an iterative method used in signal processing.

The term *recursion* is normally used in the sense of [recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), where a value $y_n$ is generally a function of $n$ and of its values $y_k$, $k<n$:

$$y_n=f(n,y_{n-1},y_{n-2},\ldots)$$

In signal processing applications, such as filtering, the index $n$ is interpreted as a *time index*. E.g., when implementing a (causal) filter, the current filter output can be computed from the current input and previous input and output values. This is a specific form of a recurrence relation. On the other hand, when talking about iteration, the iteration index is usually not related to time. I think it is this latter point that your professor referred to.

Answer (score 0):

my understand of the DSP meaning of "recursion" is that the current output depends on previous values of the output.

IIR filters, i think simply **have** to be recursive.  it's sorta in their definition.

now it is most often true that FIR filters are non-recursive, but not all implementations of FIR filters are non-recursive.  consider the moving-average or moving-sum filter:

$$ y[n] = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1} x[n-i] $$

that's the non-recursive way to implement it.  ya gotta add up all of the terms.

the recursive implementation is:

$$ y[n] = y[n-1] - x[n-N] + x[n]  $$

mathematically the same filter, but the implementation is different.  one is recursive, the other is not.

Comment: Form and implementation are usually different for recursive filters. You don't have a growing [stack of calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) to $y[n-1]$ with decreasing $n$ that ultimately resolves when $n$ is small enough that you can keep returning control until the call stack is empty. You could have that but normally don't. Instead, you start directly with the first $y[n]$ and hard-code that sequence of incrementing $n$, equivalent to the sequence of popping the call stack.